# How to reference data across multiple Android activities?

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist, android-sqlite, bundle

I would like to be able to send an `ArrayList` that is populated from data in an `SQLite` database around several Android activities without having to repopulate the array every time one activity ends and another begins. I want to populate the list originally during the "splash screen" and either send that list around to be (added to)/(edited)/(removed from) various activities. 
The list is created in a `DataManager` class which creates and populates the `ArrayList` through a series of methods it contains. I'm concerned that if I create an instance of this `DataManager` class (e.g. `myManager`) in the splash screen it will be terminated once the next activity is executed.

**Ultimately, my question is:**

How do I reference an `ArrayList` that exists in an instance of a `DataManager` class so that *as I start and finish activities*, the new information received from one `Activity` transfers over to the next?

Comment: this could easily be achieved through singleton class, you data can be crud through single instance class in of the referenced activities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another class (not an activity). Create a static reference there to your arrayList. You can clear that static reference of arraylist when you no longer need it and start it on the splash activity.

Comment: So the fault in my methods was creating an instance of the datamanager class when I could have just instantiated it within the datamanager class and statically referenced it throughout my activities?